# size_t return pointer subtraction

Tags: c, pointers

I want to rthe following error message......error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘size_t’

```
    return 0;
}

size_t strlen(const char *s1)
{



    return s1 - 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Subtracting zero from a pointer does not change the pointer, the same way that subtracting zero from a number does not change a number.

You should subtract the original pointer, not zero, to get the length:

```
size_t strlen(const char *s1) {
    const char *orig = s1;
    while (*s1) {
        s1++;
    }
    return s1 - orig;
}
```

Comment: I believe you mean `const char *orig = s1;`

Comment: i was just trying to do it without using a second variable, i thought pointer subtraction allowed for a pointer to be subtracted by an int

Comment: @Jason You are allowed to subtract an `int` from a pointer, but you get back a pointer, not an integer.